# not able to create path with single occurence of double quote in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have path in TCL as

```
set replacementPth "C:/SVN/simulation"
```

I need to create a string like

> fopen("C:/SVN/simulation

from the $replacementPth

I have tried many ways to escape the single occurence of double quote but failed.

For example

```
set x1 fopen($replacementPth
```

gives

> fopen(C:/SVN/simulation

Any help.
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a strategic backslash in front of the double quote.

```
set x1 fopen(\"$replacementPth
```

At this point, I'd probably put the whole thing in double quotes, just because it looks nicer (not that it makes any semantic difference):

```
set x1 "fopen(\"$replacementPth"
```